# How to add New line to a div contenteditable in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Basically I'm using a div with `contenteditable` as a text box. Now when I input a newline (By pressing enter) it doesn't counts it and escaps it.

Jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/pgsp7q57/3/

You can input:

```
Hello
How are you
```

And see the result by yourself which is(`hellohow are you`) But I need to get the result as:

```
Hello
How are you
```

All replies are much appreciated.

Comment: because `\n` is not an HTML entity, try wrapping your text within a textarea. you will see the difference.

Comment: @Roljhon Can you see my jsfiddle update?

Answer (score 0):

Try this [code](https://jsfiddle.net/pgsp7q57/2/).

```
var hello = "hello<br>how\nare\nyou";
document.getElementById("hey").innerHTML = hello;
```

Comment: I'm sorry my jsfiddle was a little out dated. see the update plz